# What is the encoding used by AppEngine TaskQueue when they encode byte[] arrays as Strings? 

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, character-encoding, task-queue

What is the encoding of a HTTP POST body called from the AppEngine TaskQueue service?

If I create a task via [`TaskOptions#payload(byte[], String)`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions.html#payload%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29), what will the encoding of the HTTP request body be?

Similarly, what will be the encoding of the `String` created via [`TaskOptions#param(String, byte[])`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions.html#param%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D%29) and retrieved via [`ServletRequest#getParameter(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29)?

UPDATE: **What is the charset name** I have to use in

```
req.getParameter("myParam").getBytes(charset)
```

to get back the binary data I've submitted via [`TaskOptions#param(String, byte[])`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions.html#param%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D%29) ?

It seems to be a servlet-container specific default value which is not defined in the definition for 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' at http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1 -- because all that is abstracted away in the servlet API already.

Answer (score 2):

> If I create a task via
>   TaskOptions#payload(byte[], String),
>   what will the encoding of the HTTP
>   request body be?

There is no encoding - the byte array you pass in becomes the literal body of the HTTP request.

> Similarly, what will be the encoding
>   of the String created via
>   TaskOptions#param(String, byte[]) and
>   retrieved via
>   ServletRequest#getParameter(String)?

Parameters are encoded using formencoding, as in a regular GET or POST request.

Comment: I guess you mean 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' as defined in http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1  - Thanks!

Comment: @xamde That's the content-type for a POST request that contains parameters, yes.

Comment: This encoding doesn't support binary content. `multipart/form-data` does. Surely this byte array must somehow been encoded. How else would you get a `String` out of it?

Comment: @BalusC Yes it does - bytes that aren't urlsafe are %-encoded.

Comment: %-encoding applies on characters, not bytes.

Comment: @BalusC No it doesn't. As per RFC1738, "In addition, octets may be encoded by a character triplet consisting of the character "%" followed by the two hexadecimal digits (from "0123456789ABCDEF") which forming the hexadecimal value of the octet."

Comment: This contradicts with your answer.

Comment: @BalusC How so? The argument passed to `TaskOptions#param` is a `byte[]`, and I've just explained how they're encoded (using formencoding).

Answer (score 1):

On the first one, I have no idea. I'll however do a bet on `UTF-8` since the Javadoc mentions `UTF-8` everywhere. You could debug the request body by a HTTP debugger tool like Fiddler2. You could test around with strings with UTF-8 specific characters which are transformed to byte array by `string.getBytes("UTF-8")` and then read it in the servlet side. If it returns the same characters, then the chance is definitely big that it is using UTF-8.

On the second one, that depends on the `charset` attribute in the `Content-Type` request header. This is however more than often absent (at least, when a normal webbrowser is used). You can however set it yourself by [`ServletRequest#setCharacterEncoding()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29) *before* you access any data from the request body.

```
if (request.getCharacterEncoding() == null) {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
}
```

Otherwise the platform default one will be used, as specified by [`Charset#defaultCharset()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset%28%29).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately it doesn't fit exactly to my question -- which is just rephrased. Maybe I should just experiment and hope they don't change it. However, some official documentation on this would make me happier.